# Return Postgresql query as Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

My code is as below:

```
from pandas import DataFrame


import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder 
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker 

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('<I.P>', <Port>), #Remote server IP and SSH port
    ssh_private_key=r'<Path to the key stored locally in computer>',
    ssh_username = "<username>",
    ssh_password = "<password",
    remote_bind_address=('localhost', <port>)) as server: #PostgreSQL server IP and sever port on remote machine

    server.start() #start ssh sever
    print ('Server connected via SSH')

    #connect to PostgreSQL
    local_port = str(server.local_bind_port)
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://<db_username>:<password>@127.0.0.1:' + local_port +'/db_name')

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    print ('Database session created')

    #test data retrieval 
    query = '''select * from table_name'''
    #df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
    #df = pd.read_sql_table(query, engine)
    df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
    print (df)

    session.close()
```

What I get from the output is the image as below:

[image]

But I want a more pythonic Pandas Dataframe as we see in Jupyter Notebook where I can scroll left and right and up and down.
How to achieve that?

Comment: This is not a case of "Pythonic" or not, it just a way you can show your dataframe in Jupyter notebook as an HTML table. So if you run this in Jupyter notebook and then just execute `df` in another cell, you will get a "Jupyter notebook" style table.

Comment: No. Those code I run in Jupyter and appear as it is showed above.

Comment: Jupyter is interactive. Do not call `print` but just data frame itself `df`.

Comment: I have tried it also with df only before but took long time that I quit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that print (df) returns dataframe as list. I should use display (df) but first of all, I should add this line in the begining of the code to take effect:
`enter code here`from IPython.display import display